# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #8](https://askubuntu.com/election/8) on Ask Ubuntu has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: andrew.46]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Marco Ceppi]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://askubuntu.com/election/8) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6257550686158848).

Answer (score 23):

This is very exciting!

Thank you to all who participated in the election and especially thanks to the people who stepped up to be candidates. And thank you to those who have put their trust in me by voting me into this position, I will work diligently as moderator to repay this trust.

My special thanks as well to Marco Ceppi for all his hard work on Ask Ubuntu.

And again: thank you!

Comment: welcome to the team <3

Comment: I wish you good luck andrew.46. I hope you will be the voice for the voiceless.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations